# API PHP con Android Studio enviar parametros

Tags: php, android

Tengo el siguiente codigo en android studio donde hago un llamado a una API Local
La idea es enviarle un codigo para obtener el stock de la DB

```
public void fetchStockData(String codigo) {
        // Define the URL of your API
        String apiUrl = "http://192.168.0.1/Controlador/api_stock";

        // Create the JSON object to hold the parameter
        JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonBody.put("code", codigo);
            jsonBody.put("store", 1);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d("StockData", " " + jsonBody + "");

        // Create the request
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, apiUrl, jsonBody,
                response -> {
                    List<Map<String, String>> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
                    try {
                        String status = response.getString("status");
                        if (status.equals("success")) {
                            JSONArray dataArray = response.getJSONArray("data");
                            for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject dataObject = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                Log.d("Response", " " + dataObject + "");
                            }
                        } else {
                            // Handle case where status is not "success"
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                },
                error -> {
                    // Handle errors
                    error.printStackTrace();
                });

        Volley.newRequestQueue(context).add(request);
    }
```

Aqui mi BackEnd por el momento tengo algunos datos en crudo, pero el codigo me viene en blanco en mis response.

```
public function api_stock_tiendas()
      {
          $code = trim($this->input->post('code', true));
          $store = trim($this->input->post('store', true)); 
          
          $stockData = $this->fetchStockData($code, $store);

          $response = array();
          if ($stockData) {
              $response['status'] = 'success';
              $response['data'] = $stockData;
          } else {
              $response['status'] = 'error';
              $response['message'] = 'Failed to fetch stock data';
          }
          header('Content-Type: application/json');
          echo json_encode($response);
      }

    private function fetchStockData($code, $store)
    {
        return array(
            array(
                'codigo' => $code,
                'product_name' => 'Product 1',
                'stock_quantity' => 100,
                'store' => $store 
            ),
            array(
                'codigo' => $code,
                'product_name' => 'Product 2',
                'stock_quantity' => 50,
                'store' => $store 
            ),
        );
    }
```

Estoy usando CodeIgniter framework 3
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola. ¿Puedes explicar qué significa esto en tu backend: `$this->input->post('code', true)`? Es ahí donde asignas el valor de `$code`, pero no vemos qué es `input` en ese contexto, ni lo que hace la llamada a `post` de ese objeto o propiedad llamado `input`.